# Prove that $\gcd(a+s,b+s)=1$ for infinitely many numbers $s$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Prove that  for every natural numbers $a$ and $b$, there are infinitely many numbers $s$, such  $\gcd(a+s,b+s)=1$ and $a\neq b$

I tried to use Bezout's theorem but I can't get to the result

Comment: no it isn t a fixed number we can change it , it depends to the value of and b

Comment: @AbderrahmaneDriouch  That is not what your question says.  In your question, $s$ cannot depend on $a$ or $b$.

Comment: This question does not make sense, please edit for clarity.

Comment: but i said "there are an infinity of numbers $s$

Comment: @AbderrahmaneDriouch  As stated, Saucy O'Path is correct.  There is no such number $s$.

Comment: so prove it....

Comment: If $d|a+s, d|b+s,d$ must divide $a+s-(b+s)$ Now if $(a,b)=D, d|D$

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is unclear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: I edited the question - is this what you wanted to ask? And don't demand solutions  from people, no one here is obligated to solve YOUR problems for YOU.

Comment: ok ,alright.....

Comment: The Question has been edited into a form where it can be answered (and has been) by reasoned mathematical argument, namely that as stated the claim is false but with the additional assumption that $a\neq b$, it can be proven.  I'm therefore inclined to leave open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As rightfully pointed out in the other answer, the statement trivially does not hold when $a = b$. Thus we must make the assumption that $a \neq b$. Then, my original answer holds:

Without loss of generality, $a > b$. A property of the greatest common divisor tells us that
$$
\gcd(a + s, b + s) = \gcd((a + s) - (b + s), b + s) = \gcd(a - b, b + s).
$$
Hence, if $p$ is any prime that does not divide $a - b$, we can choose $s = p - b$, and then
$$
\gcd(a + s, b + s) = \gcd(a - b, p) = 1.
$$
Since there are infinitely many primes, this shows that there are infinitely many such $s$.

Answer (score 1):

As stated the claim is obviously false: $a$ and $b$ may be equal, in which case the GCD is $|a+s|$ (assuming you meant **integer** $s$, otherwise the problem doesn't make sense), and that is equal to $1$ for exactly two values of $s$.

So you must also have the assumption that $a \ne b$. Let's assume $a < b$.

There are infinitely many primes greater than $b$. For any such prime $p$, let $s = p - b$. Then $\gcd(a+s,b+s)=\gcd(a+p-b, p) = 1$, because $p$ is prime and $ 1 < a+p-b < p$

Comment: thanks.........

Comment: Thank you for the correct addition; I hope you don't mind that I've edited it into my answer.

Comment: @MeesdeVries - Of course, especially since you also specifically referenced the other answer, you didn't simply change yours. That is the proper way to deal with such situations IMO. I wrote my answer and posted it without seeing yours. Then I saw yours and noticed it is very similar; but I left mine up, since I don't see the need to go through $a-b$. My thought was to go directly to $b+s$ being a prime, so the GCD should automatically be $1$, with essentially no other justification needed.